# wpf radio button in listbox won't check the first time

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding XyzList}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Visibility="{Binding Stop}" 
                       ToolTip="{Binding Stopp}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       Opacity="1" Width="11" Height="11" 
                       Source=stop.png"/>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Period}" 
                             IsEnabled="{Binding Ok}" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                             Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                
                             Command="Views:ValjLeveransArende.PrCommand"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I select the radio button for the first time, it will not be selected, I get the correct data, but it will not be selected.

When I try a second time it gets selected.

More information:

```
 public class XyzList: WorkViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
        }
    }
}
```

And then when I fill the rest of the data I set it like this

```
list.Add(new XyzList()
            {                    
                IsSelected = false
            });
```

Comment: What is the value of `IsSelected` when program starts? It sounds like a binding issue...

Comment: It's set to false in the code

Comment: Have you tried changing your xamlto... Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you bind `IsSelected` in two places that are both triggered by the same user action. Instead, you should keep only a single View-to-Viewmodel binding and link the different view controls to one-another.

Keep in the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Change in the `RadioButton`:

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
```

Another problem: your radiobuttons won't behave as if they belong to the same group... you may have to work with the `RadioButton.GroupName` property if you actually need their functionality. However, it's possible to completely rely on the `ListBox` for selection.

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't select the first time =((

Comment: @KickanG Do you have anything in the command or in the property setter code that could interfere with the functionality?

Comment: Added some info in my post

Comment: @KickanG the problem is, I currently have a working sample based on your question code (had to remove the unknown things like `Stopp` and `Ok`), so I just can't reproduce your issue - you should try to create a fresh WPF project, put the question code into it and verify that the issue exists there.